# How can I safely use user supplied text in JSON?

Tags: json, node.js, validation, security, express

I have a Node application that needs to take user input(a username and password) and make a request to another API with those two things included. I have a function that should do this:

```
getTokenFromLogin = function(user, pass) {    
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var options = this.options;
        options.url = endpoints.login;
        options.method = 'POST';
        options.form = {
            'username': user,
            'password': pass
        };
        request(options, function (err, httpResponse, body) {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            resolve(body);
        });
    });
    return promise;
};
```

However, theoretically, couldn't an attacker just input a string in JSON format that could manipulate my request object? If this is the case, how can I ensure that these strings are safe? I've seen two methods, JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify(), but nothing I've found clarifies what I should use and exactly how those methods could stop this kind of vulnerability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is your code is already "safe." Strings are strings (assuming you are checking the `typeof` `user` and `pass` of course) and strings cannot magically interact with objects by themselves.

Now if the server you're sending the request to is poorly designed/coded and does not properly sanitize its inputs (`user` and `pass`) when inserting into a database for example, then that's an entirely different scenario. However for making the request, there is no security issue here.

Comment: So even if someone enters a string such as _} 'options.url = 'malicous.url' ; } {_ than it will still be safe on my end?

Comment: Yes. It's just a string, you're not `eval()`ing or otherwise executing the string as if it were code.

Comment: I understand. Thanks a bunch!